# Find the numbers at which the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How can I find the integers $a$ at which the polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible over the field $\mathbb{Q}$? Thank you!
$$f(x) = 5x^4 - 6x^3 - ax^2 - 4x + 2$$

Comment: Use rational roots theorem to generate all possible rational roots, plug them in to polynomial, set that equal to $0$, solve the equations in terms of $a$. All of the $a$ you get will be the ones for which $f(x)$ is reducible for the field $\Bbb{Q}$, so for all other integers, $f(x)$ will be irreducible.

Comment: Note that if $a$ is even, then Eisenstein's criterion applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Rational Roots Theorem, the following rational numbers can be roots of this polynomial:
$$\pm \frac 1 5, \pm 1, \pm \frac 2 5, \pm 2$$
Now, plug these eight roots into $f(x)$ to get an expression in terms of $a$ and then solve for $a$. $f(x)$ is reducible for those values of $a$. I will get you started on making the equations:
$$x=\frac 1 5 \implies 5\left(\frac 1 5\right)^4 - 6\left(\frac 1 5\right)^3 - a\left(\frac 1 5\right)^2 - 4\left(\frac 1 5\right) + 2=0 \implies f(x) \text{ is reducible for } a=29$$
$$x=-\frac 1 5 \implies 5\left(-\frac 1 5\right)^4 - 6\left(-\frac 1 5\right)^3 - a\left(-\frac 1 5\right)^2 - 4\left(-\frac 1 5\right) + 2=0 \\ \implies f(x) \text{ is reducible for } a=\frac{357}{3}$$
Note that the last equation above does not give us an integer solution, so we ignore it.

---

However, we also need to find the values of $a$ for which the polynomial can be factored into two quadratics. The product of the leading coefficients must be $5$ and the product of the constants must be $2$, so assuming positive leading coefficients, there are four cases:
$$(5x^2+Ax+1)(x^2+Bx+2)$$
Here, the $x^3$ term is $(A+5B)x^3$ and the $x$ term is $(2A+B)x$, so we have:
$$A+5B=-6 \wedge 2A+B=-4 \implies (A,B)=\left(-\frac{14}{9}, -\frac{8}{9}\right)$$
We don't get integer solutions here, so we ignore this. The next case is:
$$(5x^2+Ax-1)(x^2+Bx-2)$$
Here, the $x^3$ term is $(A+5B)x^3$ and the $x$ term is $(-2A-B)x$, so we have:
$$A+5B=-6 \wedge -2A-B=-4 \implies (A,B)=\left(\frac{26}{9}, -\frac{16}{9}\right)$$
We don't get integer solutions here, so we ignore this. The next case is:
$$(5x^2+Ax+2)(x^2+Bx+1)$$
Here, the $x^3$ term is $(A+5B)x^3$ and the $x$ term is $(A+2B)x$, so we have:
$$A+5B=-6 \wedge A+2B=-4 \implies (A,B)=\left(-\frac{8}{3}, -\frac{2}{3}\right)$$
We don't get integer solutions here, so we ignore this. The next case is:
$$(5x^2+Ax-2)(x^2+Bx-1)$$
Here, the $x^3$ term is $(A+5B)x^3$ and the $x$ term is $(-A-2B)x$, so we have:
$$A+5B=-6 \wedge -A-2B=-4 \implies (A,B)=\left(\frac{32}{3}, -\frac{10}{3}\right)$$
We don't get integer solutions here, so we ignore this.

Therefore, factoring into two quadratics yield no solutions for $a$, so we only have to worry about the $a$ we solved for in the first part of this answer.

Comment: Further I need to continue the calculation for the other numbers and find $a$ which is not a rational number?

Comment: Yes, you need to continue the equations according to the examples in my answer with the other six roots and find the other integer solutions for $a$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry. I don't see why the polynomial is irreducible when it has no roots?

Comment: @user60589 Oh, wait...I didn't consider the case where it's factorable into two quadratics. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Polynomial is reducible if it has a rationnal roots or if it can factored into the product ot two non-constant polynomials. I think more about it you can read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial

Comment: @user60589 I've proven that the polynomial can not be factored into two polynomials above.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Thank's! Now I am happy! :)